# Calculated field in RoR (act as an ActiveRecord method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, calculated-columns

I am building an app for cognitive tests in Rails.
I have a number of tests (`Quiz` objects) for my visitors. In the home page I want to show only quizzes that are ready for consumption: they must have a number of questions and a number of possible answers.
Of course I could query with SQL, or create a class method retrying all objects where `Quiz.questions.size > 1 && Quiz.answer.size > 1`.
Still, I'd like a more elegant/abstracted way.
Is there a way to query have a 'ready' method acting as if it were an ActiveRecord method, so I can call `Quiz.find_all_by_ready(1)` and put `ready` in any quiz condition?
Caching is a possibility, I was wondering if there was a dynamic alternative. How would a rails guru solve the problem?

Cheers,
Davide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of named_scope and counter_caches you could do something like this:

```
class Quiz < AR:B
    named_scope :ready, :conditions => ['quizes.questions_count > 0 AND quizes.answers_count > 0']
end

@quizes = Quiz.ready
```

I hope this helps!